# Where to find raw data about clinical trials?

Tags: dataset, teaching, clinical-trials

I wish to use raw data about clinical trials for the end year examination of my master students. These data could deal with any kind of molecule as long as the trials were complete (Phase 1 to 4).

Do you have an idea where to find such a free dataset on the web ?

Comment: +1, good question, and you're in good company with it, see commentary by Andrew Vickers "Whose data set is it anyway? Sharing raw data from randomized trials" (http://www.trialsjournal.com/content/7/1/15)

Comment: I think this is on-topix, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248001/dataset-for-studying-and-teaching-fishers-exact-test  (and there are many other open Qs about datasets for teaching.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a look at the [Clinical Trials Network](http://www.ctndatashare.org/), where data are available in [CDISC](http://www.cdisc.org/) format. You must agree to their terms and conditions, although the following point might be of concern for teaching purpose:

> To retain control over the received data, and not to transfer any
>   portion of the received data, with or without charge, to any other
>   entity or individual

(Anyway, I think that you can just send an email to the contact support to check that their data can be used for teaching.)

The [NIDKK Data Repository](https://www.niddkrepository.org/) is specifically concerned with studies on kidney and liver disease, and diabete; however, you have to submit an application.

Otherwise, perhaps the [ADNI](http://www.adni-info.org/) project, which aims at characterizing change in cognitive functions and brain structures with age, with a particular emphasis on Alzheimer's disease and neuroimaging, might be interesting. This is not a clinical trial, but available data include: demographics, clinical and cognitive data, neuroimaging (MRI/PET) data. Details about protocols and data can be found under [ADNI Scientist's Home](http://www.adni-info.org/Scientists/ADNIScientistsHome.aspx), and data are available on [ADCS](http://adcs.org/) website.

There doesn't seem to be anything related to RCTs on http://www.infochimps.com/. However, I remember having seen some clinical data used with the [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) software, as e.g. on this page: [Data mining to predict patient outcome in a clinical trial of a lung cancer treatment](http://cs-people.bu.edu/dgs/courses/cs105/hall_of_fame/cook.html).

Comment: The clinical trials network is a NIDA subsidiary so it's only about drug abuse data.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [NIMH](http://www.nimh.nih.gov/trials/datasets/nimh-procedures-for-requesting-data-sets.shtml) has a number of slightly lobotomized data sets available, although I have no idea what the data use agreements entail. This will be a problem for almost every trial you come across I suspect - the need to either prevent their trial results from getting scooped, health information privacy concerns, or both.

Others I've found:

- National Heart, Lung and Blood Institute has a ["teaching" data set](https://biolincc.nhlbi.nih.gov/teaching/).

I'll edit this answer if the list grows. There's also always simulating a data set so it matches the results of a published trial.

Comment: Tks a lot, I didn't know these websites !

Answer (score 3):

You can find details of a trial downloadable in an XML format from http://clinicaltrials.gov/

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://yoda.yale.edu/ and https://www.clinicalstudydatarequest.com/ both of which require lengthy applications.